# Easily edit and run Ruby on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, user-interface

I'm starting right from the beginning with Ruby to learn the ropes but have a quick query.  Currently I am writing small test bits of code such as:

```
puts 'Hello World'
```

etc. into EditRocket, saving as test1.rb and then opening Terminal on my Mac and executing the 'program' with:

`ruby test1.rb`

This is becoming a little tedious with the backwards and forwarding so I was wondering if there was a more 'user friendly' approach to writing a bit of Ruby code and then executing it live to get a result as you would SQL code in SQL Server for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running irb in Terminal will run a Ruby read-eval-print loop that will evaluate each line of Ruby that you type. Just type "irb" in Terminal to start, and "exit" from within irb to exit.

Comment: Thanks, why `puts 1..3` doesn't print `1 2 3` and prints `1..3`?

Answer (score 3):

Try `irb`, the interactive Ruby interpreter.

Comment: Hey thanks for that - I've tried that but as far as I can see that only allows you to write / execute 1 line of code at a time.  Am I missing something obvious that allows for multiple lines of code?

Comment: It shows you the return value of any operation you execute, but it all is executed in the same environment, meaning you can write statements that depend on previous statements.

Comment: So sorry just to clarify if I want to run a bit of multi-line code using 'irb'  such as:

'puts "Hello World'
'puts " "'
'puts "Goodbye'

I'd write one line at a time, hit enter after each line to run it?

Comment: @AppSlapp You can separate commands with semicolons if you really feel the need to put them on the same line, but what @Matthew means is that you can write `x = 42` on one line and then `puts "x is #{x}"` on the next line and it will output the value of that variable, just like it would in a multi-line program.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend TextMate as a text editor for Ruby. There is also a great tool called IRB, which is a dynamic Ruby console.

Comment: In TextMate command+R shortcut to run your code with out having to use the terminal.

Comment: This runs basic code but it doesn't generate areas for input into the code does it?  Such as using: comment = gets.chomp .  I may be missing something though?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the EditRocket website](http://www.editrocket.com/features/ruby_editor.html):

> Users can execute Ruby programs and view the standard and error output using the `Tools -> Execute Program -> Execute Ruby Program` menu option.

With OS X, you can create your own keyboard shortcut for any menu in any application. Here's [a guide](http://lifehacker.com/343328/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-any-menu-action-in-any-program) on doing this.

**Edit**: Downloading a trial of this program and running it, it seems their documentation is wrong or outdated, as the menu option is `Tools -> Ruby -> Execute Program`. Further, this is rather tedious - it opens an unfriendly dialog each time you want to re-run the program allowing you to set the interpreter and command-line parameters, and more.

I, too, recommend that you try out (and buy, if you like it) [TextMate](http://macromates.com/); it's a great text editor and it's workflow for running Ruby is far better.

Answer (score 1):

I like TextMate for simple Ruby coding and quick examples that I post here, for the reasons mentioned by others.

For heavy coding I use [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) on Mac OS, or [Vim or Gvim](http://www.vim.org/) on Linux or Windows. It's not as friendly but is extremely powerful, and, is the same editor everywhere, including using the same fonts and themes and custom changes I've made.

ActiveState has [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), which is a really nice blend of editor features, including having a vi mode. It's free so you don't lose anything trying it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to watch your files and run them whenever you save.